# XML schema file (.xsd) has different size on Linux and Windows

Tags: xml, linux, windows, file, schema

I have a XML schema file (.xsd) and it is showing different size on Linux and Windows. What can be the reason of it?

When I compare both files (on Windows) then their data is same, perhaps the file size is still different. Windows file is few hundred bytes bigger than the Linux counterpart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unix and windows traditionally have different line-endings in text-files (such as XML).

While Linux uses `LF` (aka `\n`), Windows uses `CRLF` (aka `\r\n`).

The latter takes 2 bytes, whereas the former only needs a single bytes.

So if you create your file in a "native" way (e.g. modern version vontrol systems will automatically convert the line-endings based on the system the file is checked out), you will end up with the w32 files being slightly larger (one byte per line) than their unix version.

Comment: What is the remedy of it then?

Comment: in order to apply a remedy, you must first have a problem. there is no inherent problem with different line-endings (apart from the confusion it causes) and different file-sizes. so why do you need to "fix" it?

Comment: I meant, how can we make sure that a file has same line ending on Linux and Windows - no matter on which editor and OS this file is created. Is it possible to do?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve and why? some editors (`notepad` comes to my mind) might have problems when being presented with a non-native line-ending. Also you haven't specified *anything* about the transport mechanism you are using (How you distribute the files), so you are basically asking: "How can I create files with a given EOL on any editor and OS?" - which is of course impossible, since any editor can choose to use whatever line-ending they like.

Comment: Actually I wanted to calculate the CRC of the schema file for validation before using it (making sure it is not tampered by the user). Because of this LF and CRLF difference on Win and Linux, the CRC is calculated differently. I wanted to keep the files same for both platforms, but it seems tedious to do. So, I stored 2 CRCs - different for both platforms.